# call a component from another component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have an alert component like in this video: https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/21 And I have another component (Book). When a book was created how can I call Alert component in the success callback function like this:

```
<alert>A book was created successfully !!!</alert>
```

I am a newbie in using vue.js. Thank you for your help.

**Updated:** This is my code

```
submit: function () {
    this.$http.post('/api/books/add', {
        data: this.data,
    }).then(function (response) {
        // I want to use Alert component right here to notice to users.
    }, function (response) {
    });
}
```

**Update 2:**
Alert Component

```
<template>
    <div class="Alert Alert--{{ type | capitalize }}"
         v-show="show"
         transition="fade"
    >
        <slot></slot>

        <span class="Alert__close"
              v-show="important"
              @click="show = false"
        >
            x
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: {
            type: { default: 'info' },
            timeout: { default: 3000 },
            important: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {show: true};
        },

        ready() {
            if (!this.important)
            {
                setTimeout(
                    () => this.show = false,
                        this.timeout
                    )
            }

        }
    }

</script>

<style>
    .Alert {
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .Alert__close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .Alert--Info {
        background: #e3e3e3;
    }

    .fade-transition {
        transition: opacity 1s ease;
    }

    .fade-leave {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

And in Book.vue I want to do like this:

```
// resources/assets/js/components/Book.vue
<template>
    .....
    <alert>A book was created successfully !!!</alert>

    //Create book form
    ....
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            submit: function () {
                    this.$http.post('/api/books/add', {
                    data: this.data,
                }).then(function (response) {
                     this.$refs.alert
                }, function (response) {
                });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Care to add some code... I can tell you there is more than one way to do that. Your solution would depend on your code. Whatever you have... will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this JSfiddle does what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeemisme/s0f5xjxu/

I used a button press rather than a server response to trigger the alert, and changed a few method names, but principle is the same.

The alert component is nested inside the button component. Button passes a showalert prop to the alert component with the sync modifier set.

```html
 <alert :showalert.sync="showalert" type="default" :important="true">A book was saved successfully</alert>
```

Press the button, showalert is set to 'true', 'true' passed to alert as prop, alert displays as v-show condition is now true,

```html
data() {
          //by default we're not showing alert.
          //will pass to alert as a prop when button pressed
          //or when response from server in your case
          return {
            showalert: false
          };
        },
```

a watch on the showalert prop in alert component sees a change and triggers a method that sets showalert back to 'false' after whatever many seconds set in timeout property.

```html
            //this method is triggered by 'watch', below
            //when 'showalert' value changes it sets the timeout
            methods: {
              triggerTimeout: function() {
                //don't run when detect change to false
                if (this.showalert === true) {
                  setTimeout(
                    () => this.showalert = false,
                    this.timeout
                  )
                }
              },
            },

            watch: {
              // detect showalert being set to true and run method
              'showalert': 'triggerTimeout',
            }
```

Because this prop is synched back to parent, button state updated too.

It works but using watch etc. feels overblown. Vue may have a better way to handle this. I'm new to Vue so somebody with more knowledge might chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data property

```
alertShow: false
```

Next, in the callback:

```
this.alertshow = true;
```

When you want to remove it, set it to false.

In the component add a directive:

```
v-show="alertshow"
```

Update:

Add a components attribute to block component.

```
components: {Alert},
```

Next outside of the component, import the Alert component file:

```
import Alert from './directory/Alert.vue'
```

The above is if you are using vueify. Otherwise, add a component using

```
Vue.component
```

Check out the docs.

Update 2:

Your code, with the changes:

```
<script>
import Alert from './directory/alert.vue';
export default {

    components: {
        Alert
    },

    methods: {
        submit: function () {
                this.$http.post('/api/books/add', {
                data: this.data,
            }).then(function (response) {
                 this.$refs.alert
            }, function (response) {
            });
}
```

Comment: So how can I call the alert component in book component?

Comment: I'm using veuify and already import Alert in the main.js. But I can't call alert in Book.vue. It just showed the text: A book was created successfully !!!

Comment: What does your Alert component look like? Post code.

Comment: So, in your book component you need to add a components attribute and then within the script tags import the Alert component file.

Comment: Can you show me a example call a component in another component. I am a newbie in using vue.js. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you still have problems, make a fiddle and post.